# Function only returns on events

Tags: javascript, function, events, dom-events

I am calling a function with `console.log(openDialog())` and `openDialog()` creates a modal window and the function only returns on certain events.

My `openDialog()` is like

```
function openDialog() {
  // do some html

  //
  buttonElement.onclick = function () {
    return 'some value';
  }
}
```

the problem is that when I call `console.log(openDialog())`, it automatically sees that my function doesn't return a value, so it just returns `undefined`. I want it to wait until my function `openDialog()` has returned something.

Maybe it's promises?

## Edit

Is it just like this with callback?

```
function openDialog(cb) {
  // do some html

  buttonElement.onclick = function () {
    return cb('some value');
  }
}

console.log(openDialog(function (value) {
  return value;
});
```

Comment: The way you do it is to have your console statement in the callback of the event (`onClick`). I am assuming you want to print `'some value'` on your `console.log`?

Comment: Functions are synchronous, you can't use `promise` on them. Why do you need `openDialog()` to return a value?

Comment: Even aside from the main problem that `openDialog()` will return immediately, the return value from a click handler is used by the browser to decide whether to cancel the default behaviour of the click, so that part doesn't make sense either.

Comment: I am trying to make a customized `prompt()`, so I want to show the dialog and get what the user writes in the dialog, which is also why the events are only active inside the function.

Comment: You need to restructure the code to use callbacks. That is, have `openDialog()` accept a callback function as an argument, then within your click handler call that callback function to do whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, supposing you're trying to create a customized `prompt()`, you have to keep in mind that we cannot do it synchronous.

This uses the native `prompt` function which is synchronous:

```
var result = prompt("What's your name");
```

You cannot create a function like that. Instead you need to make it asynchronous: using callbacks (or promises).

#### Simple callback interface

```js
function openDialog(buttonElement, cb) {
  buttonElement.onclick = function () {
    cb('some value');
  }
}

// Open the dialog
openDialog(document.querySelector("button"), function (result) {
  // After getting the result, this will be called
  alert(result);  
});
```

```html
<button>Submit</button>
```

#### Promise interface

```js
function openDialog(buttonElement) {
  var resolve = null;
  var promise = new Promise(function (_resolve) {
    resolve = _resolve;
  });
  buttonElement.onclick = function () {
    resolve('some value');
  }
  return promise;
}

// Open the dialog
openDialog(document.querySelector("button")).then(function (result) {
  // After getting the result, this will be called
  alert(result);  
});
```

```html
<button>Submit</button>
```

---

If you want to send errors in the callback as well, you just have to call the `callback` function with an error as first argument. In the Promises case, use the `reject` function:

```js
function openDialog(buttonElement) {
  var resolve = null;
  var reject = null;
  var promise = new Promise(function (_resolve, _reject) {
    resolve = _resolve;
    reject = _reject;
  });
  buttonElement.onclick = function () {
    var name = your_name.value;
    if (!name) {
      return reject(new Error("Please enter a name in the input."));
    }
    resolve(name);
  }
  return promise;
}

// Open the dialog
openDialog(document.querySelector("button")).then(function (result) {
  // After getting the result, this will be called
  alert(result);  
}).catch(function (err) {
  alert(err.message);
});
```

```html
<input id="your_name" />
<button>Submit</button>
```

For callback situation, just call `cb(null, name)` for success and `cb(new Error("Please enter a valid name"))` for error. Then you will call it like this:

```
openDialog(document.querySelector("button"), function (err, result) {
  if (err) { return alert(err.message); }
  // After getting the result, this will be called
  alert(result);  
});
```

Comment: Great. Thanks! I have seen many code examples with `function (err, result) {` or `.then(result => ...).catch(err => ...)`. How would I structure the code, so it can return errors as well?

Comment: @Jamgreen You're welcome! I added an example for that as well. :)